# tub won't drain – I think lift bucket broke off

Tags: bathtub

My tub won't drain. I tried drain cleaner, but then realized the "sound" of tripping the lift lever was not the same as in our other tub, making me think the mechanism to lift the drain plug "bucket" has broken. How do I verify, and fix?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the overflow spout and grab the rod and see.

Comment: So if it IS broken, how do I fix it? It's a 1955 home, original tub and fixtures

Comment: If you can get the stop bucket up, you might be able to hook it back on. If not, you'll have to buy a new setup.